# Incorrect syntax near 'float'.\r\nMust declare the scalar variable \"@\"."

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Tengo una tabla en una base de datos SQL Server 2014 en la cual tengo los campos, los cuales pueden ser nulos:

```
id int
nombre varchar
27 float
28 float
29 float
```

Sucede que el usuario ingresa los datos desde un formulario para guardarlos en la tabla ya mencionada. Ahora tengo un DropdownList que contiene los números 27, 28 y 29, entonces el usuario elige uno para guardarlo en la base de datos iniciando por el numero que elija en el dropdownlist y cierto numero ingresado en numero.Text se va a ir incrementando.

pero en la linea:

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[" + i + "]", numero.Text);
```

Marca error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'float'.\r\nMust declare the scalar variable \"@\"."

Aqui mi codigo completo:

```
try{
    int semana_inicio = Convert.ToInt32(Semana1.SelectedValue.ToString());
    con.Open();
    string query = "INSERT INTO tbl (id, nombre, [27],[28],[29]) values(@id,@nombre, @[27],@[28],@[29])";
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["id"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre.Text);
    float x = 0;
    if (float.TryParse(numero.Text, out x))
    {
    j = 0.05;
    i = semana_inicio;
    k = j;
    double cjs = k * x;
    for (int a = 1; a <= 3; a++)
    {
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@["+i+"]", cjs);
        j = k + 0.05;
        i = semana_inicio + a;
    }
    }
    }
    int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    if (result < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    } 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    error.Visible = true;
    error.Text = ex.ToString();
}
return false;
```

Comment: Tienes en tu query tres columnas con un numero (27,28, y 29)(por cierto, muy mala idea) y sin embargo solo añades una en los parametros. Y por ultimo, comprueba que valor exacto tiene `i` y `numero`, porque en principio esa linea donde dices te da error es correcta.

Comment: Las  tres columnas con un numero (27,28, y 29) debo agregar las 3 porque no se sabe en cual guardara el dato el usuario, i y numero tienen datos correctos

Comment: No me has entendido creo. Al añadir los parámetros solo estas añadiendo tres parámetros, cuando en tu query hay 5 (`@id,@nombre, @[27],@[28],@[29]`)

Comment: y como debería añadirlos todos si no se sabe cual va a elegir el usuario?, es decir que valor le daria a los otros 2 que deben quedar nulos?

Comment: Prueba cambiando la query a algo como `"INSERT INTO tbl (id, nombre, [" + i + "]) values(@id,@nombre, @columna)";` y luego en los parametros, manten los dos primeros y el tercero pon `command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@columna", numero.Text);`

Comment: y en caso de que tuviera que guardar un valor en dos o hasta en las 3 columnas?

Comment: En ese caso,deberías usar una query diferende dependiendo de cuantos valores fueran

Comment: podria hacer algo asi : "INSERT INTO tbl (id, nombre, [" + i + "], [" + i + "],etc) values(@id,@nombre, @columna,@columna2,etc)"; o es incorrecto?

Comment: Perfectamente,siempre y cuando coincidan el numero de columnas con el de values y con el de parametros que agregas

Comment: Bien complique un poco mas el codigo a ver si puedes ayudarme. Gracias @Pikoh

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
    try{
        int i= Convert.ToInt32(Semana1.SelectedValue.ToString());
        con.Open();

        string query = "INSERT INTO tbl (nombre,[27],[28], [29]) values(@nombre,@27,@28, @29)";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, con));

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Session["id"]);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombre", nombre.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + i + "", numero.Text);

        //Aqui creo que te faltan los campos 28 y 29 si no te podrían dar error por falta de datos
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@28", 0f);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@29", 0f);

        int result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

        if (result < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        } 
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
        error.Visible = true;
        error.Text = ex.ToString();
   }

   return false;
```

Mencionar que usar números como nombres de columnas es mala idea, no se recomienda dentro de las buenas prácticas en el nombrado de columnas.

Saludos

Comment: Por que crees que esto solucionaría el problema del op? Sería interesante que explicaras un poco cual crees que es su error, y como esto lo resuelve